# SimpleNaturalIdLoadAccess' load method returns a HibernateProxy

Tags: hibernate

Is it me who misunderstands the documentation for *load*, or specifically *loadOptional*, that states:

The *load* methods javadoc:

> Return the persistent instance with the given natural id value, or
> null if there is no such persistent instance. If the instance is
> already associated with the session, return that instance,
> initializing it if needed. This method never returns an uninitialized
> instance. Params: naturalIdValue – The value of the natural-id for the
> entity to retrieve Returns: The persistent instance or null

*loadOptional*'s:

> Same semantic as load except that here Optional is returned to handle
> nullability.

I would expect that *This method never returns an uninitialized instance* to mean that I would never get a HibernateProxy instance back - but indeed I do, when I look in my debugger, which in turn causes a ClassCastException with the following message:

> ExportBatch$HibernateProxy$h16E0GPh cannot be cast to class
> DkEkapitalExportBatch

Because the javadoc for the *getReference* method is documented as following, it only further adds to my confusion:

> This method might return a proxied instance that is initialized
> on-demand

Answer (score 1):

There is this thing in JPA that requires object identity to be retained for a persistent entity throughout the whole managed lifecycle. This is probably what is confusing you. If you have a proxy for a persistent entity already associated with your current persistence context, you will always receive this proxy object back, but the underlying entity will be initialized. So any calls to the methods of the entity will succeed without additional database access.
If you want the underlying object, you need to narrow the object by using `org.hibernate.Hibernate#unproxy(java.lang.Object)`

Comment: I am only confused by the documentation. I understand the lifecycle and have already implemented an unproxy method call, if necessary.

Maybe it's just me, but it is especially because the _getReference_ methods documentation explicitly states that it might return a proxied instance, that I just assumed that this is not the case, and would really prefer a method that doesn't require me to check if the managed object returned is proxy and then manually having to unproxy.
I thought, from reading the documentation, that this was the exact difference between _getReference_ and _load_

Comment: Like I wrote, in case of an empty persistence context, it behaves this way, but JPA requires the object identity to be preserved. It shouldn't matter though if you have a proxy or not. Maybe you just need to expose some method on your entity that does what you need instead of doing instanceof checks.

Comment: I truly appreciate you taking the time to answer. But I really just wanted to know if this was the intended behavior of this method given the javadoc for the load and getReference methods. I would still argue that the javadoc is misleading after reading both of your answers and then re-reading the documentation, but, again, maybe that is just me. Unfortunately, because of legacy constraints, I am forced into instanceof checks. In this specific case, because of a ClassCastException.

Comment: It's not like there is an explicit section in the JPA spec about this, but it is the consequence of other requirements. It's unfortunate but that is how it is. With Hibernate 6 we are thinking about introducing a mode where you will actually receive a proxy of the proper subtype but as you can imagine, this might cause some extra queries or joins in order to determine the actual type of the entity.